# How do I remove the Centos 7 Desktop (Hot Corner) top right effect?

Tags: javascript, linux, desktop, centos7, gnome-3

So I have a fresh install of Centos 7 Desktop version. It uses gnome 3.8 and I have multiple monitors. When I go left to right with my mouse on the top portion of the screen, it shows me all my open windows, side by side. I can also hit the windows (Overview Mode) button to see the same effect. It's distracting me and making me waste time and my train of thought.

How can I disable this feature?

I checked the tweak tool and nothing. When I tried googling it, everyone says is a CompizConfig setting. Well I don't have a compiz config tool.

Comment: If you're going to try and close, add a comment.

Comment: better to post an answer with an explanation on how you solved your problem.

Comment: You didn't give me a chance yet! But at last, it is posted!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I JUST figured this out for CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804, it's Oct 6, 2018 today.

So this has been made vastly easier by the people who make CentOS.

```
yum install gnome-tweak-tool gnome-shell-extension-no-hot-corner
```

Then, you should find it in your Applications -> Utilities -> Tweak Tool -> Extensions -> "No topleft hot corner". If the tweak tool is there but the extension is not, try rebooting. I needed to reboot, but the tutorial that I found said I shouldn't need to.

If youu don't find "No topleft hot corner" in Extensions section of Tweak Tool, Click "Get More Extensions" and search for "No topleft hot corner". Download it and add it in Extensions section and you are done.

Comment: Appears this extension has been out for over 5 years... Man how I wish I knew about this plugin... Though as a note, this extension isn't made by the CentOS team. Going to opt to mark your answer correct over mine. While both are correct, this is way easier! Thanks :)

Comment: In CentOS 7.6, the shortcut has moved to Applications > Accessories > Tweaks. And the executable was renamed from gnome-tweak-tool to gnome-tweaks, though the yum package name is still gnome-tweak-tool.

Answer (score 3):

Took a while but I found the culprit! It lives within `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js` Just look for the function below and comment out the code inside. Afterwards, type `Alt+F2` and type `restart`. It's take a second or two and will only reset gnome. You might have to do a wireless re-login and system re-log, but all your applications stay alive.

```
_toggleOverview: function() {
    //if (this._monitor.inFullscreen)
        return;

    /*if (Main.overview.shouldToggleByCornerOrButton()) {
        this._rippleAnimation();
        Main.overview.toggle();
    }*/
},
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer pertains to gnome 3.22 but I'm still writing this answer hoping that it might help somebody. I lost hours trying various suggested ideas until finally managed to do it in a correct way.

Find your Gnome shell version:

> gnome-shell --version

Download no-topleft-hot-corner extension from gnome extensions, its ID is currently 118: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/

In my case zip was: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/nohotcorner%40azuri.free.fr.v16.shell-extension.zip

Unpack zip on correct place, I also needed to change the permissions for one of the files.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p "/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr"
$ sudo unzip -o ~/Downloads/nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr.v16.shell-extension.zip -d "/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr"
$ sudo chmod 664 nohotcorner@azuri.free.fr/metadata.json
```

Restart gnome after the installation

```
$ gnome-shell --replace &
```

Then restart the Tweak tool as well and activate the extension within it.

Note: I first tried installing the extension in user space, which did not work. Then I tried installing it in system space, and finally got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Applications -> Utilities -> Tweak Tool -> Extensions.
Now check option as "No topleft hot corner" and make it as "ON".

But if you don't find "No topleft hot corner" then check for options in Extension section of Tweak Tool, then in Extensions section of Tweak Tool, Click "Get More Extensions". Search for "No topleft hot corner" in the website opened after clicking on it. Extract the downloaded file. You will get two files in it. Now add <.json> out of two in Extensions section and you are done.